# GWT Java overlay for inner JSON object

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, overlay

I have a question regarding creating of GWT Java overlays for a JSON object.

```
"flightTracks": [
{
"flightId": 287679776,
"carrierFsCode": "AA",
"flightNumber": "100",
"departureAirportFsCode": "JFK",
"arrivalAirportFsCode": "LHR",
"departureDate": {
"dateLocal": "2013-02-05T18:15:00.000",
"dateUtc": "2013-02-05T23:15:00.000Z"
},
"equipment": "777",
"bearing": 51.350983507381706,
"positions": [],
"waypoints": [
 {
 "lon": -73.76667022705078,
 "lat": 40.63333511352539
 },
.....many different waypoints here.........
 {
 "lon": -73.76667022705078,
 "lat": 40.61666488647461
 },
],
```

I have been told that the inner field "waypoints" is an array, which can be accessed the following way.

```
public final native double getWaypointsLatitude() /*-{
    return this.waypoints[0].lat;
}-*/;
```

With this method, I just get the double value at the position 0.
But I would need all positions which are contained in the array.

I also tried this:

```
public static final native double[] getLongitude() /*-{

    var longitudes = new Array();

    {
        for (i = 0; i < this.waypoints.length; i++) {
            longitudes[i] = this.waypoints[i];
        }
    }

    return longitudes;
}-*/;
```

Later, I would like to access this method from my GWT Java code, doing something like the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i< entry.getLongitude().length; i++ ){
hp.add(new Label(""+ entry.getLongitude(i)));

}
```

But that is not working at all (I also tried different approaches, none of it worked.)

Could someone please tell me how I could access the lon/lats from the inner array "waypoints" using a loop in the Java GWT code?

Thank you so much already for an answer!

Answer (score 3):

First, the reason your code doesn't work is because a JavaScript Array is represented as a `JavaScriptObject` in Java land (when passed through the JSNI boundaries), and can more specifically be cast as a `JsArray` or in your case a `JsArrayNumber`.

That said, you'd better map in Java the exact same structure you have in JavaScript, with a `Coordinates` object:

```java
public class Coordinates extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected Coordinates() { }

  public final native double getLatitude() /*-{ return this.latitude; }-*/;
  public final native double getLongitude() /*-{ return this.longitude; }-*/;
}
```

And in the `FlightTrack` object:

```java
public final native JsArray<Coordinates> getWaypoints() /*-{ return this.waypoints; }-*/;
```

You can then loop over your waypoints and extract their longitudes:

```java
JsArray<Coordinate> waypoints = entry.getWaypoints();
for (int i = 0, l = waypoints.length(); i < l; i++) {
  hp.add(new Label("" + waypoints.get(i).getLongitude());
}
```

---

Note: your `for` loop was under-optimized: `getLongitude()` would construct an Array just for the sake of reading its length, and you'd do that at each iteration; instead of just using a `getLongitudeCount()`:

```java
public native final int getLongitudeCount() /*-{ return this.waypoints.length; }-*/;
public native final double getLongitude(int i) /*-{ return this.waypoints[i].longitude; }-*/;
```

I don't think flattening your API this way has any advantage though (quite the contrary actually), so I'd rather go with more `JavaScriptObject` subclasses mapping closely your structure in Java (as proposed above).

Comment: I just tried it and it works great! You really saved my ass mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONParser aso following:

```
JSONValue root = JSONParser.parseStrict(jsonString);
JSONObject obj = root.isObject();
JSONValue waypoints = obj.get("waypoints");
JSONNumber lon = obj.get("lon").isNumber();
double num = lon.doubleValue();
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try out both solutions!